# Brython problem: HTML layout tag filled with in *.textContent not rendered

Tags: javascript, html, brython

Just starting out playing with Brython. I'm running into a basic(?) problem.

I have:

```
<body onload="brython()">
<div id="demo"></div>
```

and

```
<script type="text/python3">
from browser import document
document["demo"].textContent = "foo<p/>foo" 
</script>
```

The code runs fine, but renders in the browser as `"foo<p/>foo"`. In other words, the browser does not evaluate the `<p/>` tag in the text of `demo` element inserted there by Brython.

When I do this with JavaScript (`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "foo<p/>foo"`) the `<p/>` tag is evaluated just fine.

My understanding is that the function `brython()` translates the Python code into JS after which the browser evaluates the resulting JS. But if this is so, why isn't the `<p/>` tag in the `demo` element evaluated?

Also, how do I fix this?

Thanks for helping,
Rene

Comment: `document["demo"].innerHTML = "foo<br>foo"` should do the trick (for paragraphs it's `<p>...some content...</p>`): https://jsfiddle.net/3ozfn6d1/

Comment: Thank you much!
Rene